# PowerShell - import CSV with # as the first header

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem importing this CSV and extracting the specific columns that  I need.
If I manually remove the first column or change the column heading to anything else and save the CSV, then it works.
But If I have "#" as the first column heading it messes up. and the output is not correct and only one random column is shown.

**CSV headers**

[image: CSV image]

**Code:**

```
 $Headers = @(
    "Workstation Type"
    "Model"
    "Asset Tag"  
)
Import-Csv 'C:\CSVFiles\DeployedInventory_Workstations.csv' | Select $Headers| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\CSVFiles\DeployedInventory_Workstations2x.csv'-NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `#` as the first column name causes [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) to interpret the header line as a *comment line* - see [GitHub issue #13857](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13857).

You can work around this by specifying an alternative header via the `-Header` parameter:

```
$inputHeaders = 'HashSign', 'Asset Tag', 'Workstation Type', 'Make', 'Model'
$headers = 'Workstation Type', 'Model', 'Asset Tag'

Import-Csv C:\CSVFiles\DeployedInventory_Workstations.csv -Header $inputHeaders | 
  Select-Object $headers | 
    Export-Csv C:\CSVFiles\DeployedInventory_Workstations2x.csv -NoTypeInformation
```